# regular expression to remove space inside quotations

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a HTML code that I should clean it. After removing extra classes, inside class quotations I have extra space before and after class quotations. Also more than one space between class names.

I want to remove:
- extra leading and trailing space only inside class quotations
- have one space between class names inside class quotations

Is there any regular expression solution for this?

Comment: like what? can you give an example?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Pinty - I have a HTML code that is generated by drag and drop. I should clean the HTML and remove any extra class or element that has left by drag and drop. Then generate a beautified HTML code for user to download.

Comment: You could use three separate regex expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could use

```
myVar.replace(/\b\s{2,}\b/g, "");
```

to replace all extra spaces between two words.

2) You could then do

```
myVar.replace(/\b\s+\"/g, '"');
```

to replace all spaces between the end of a word and a quote.

3) You could finally do

```
myVar.replace(/\"\s+\b/g, '"');
```

to replace all spaces between a quote and the beginning of a word.