# Is there any way to remove extra white space in JSX classname strings?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, eslint, webstorm, prettier

I'm using React and Tailwind in WebStorm. How can I configure ESLint or Prettier to automatically remove the extra whitespace between 'text-3xl' and 'font-bold' in the JSX classname string below?

```
<h1 className="text-3xl     font-bold underline"> Intake Page</h1>
```

I've tried all the ESLint and Prettier plugins I can think of including 'eslint-plugin-tailwindcss' and 'prettier-plugin-tailwindcss'.

Below is the.eslintrc.cjs file I have at this moment.

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "standard-with-typescript",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:tailwindcss/recommended",
  ],
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  rules: {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
  },
};
```

I found this [Github issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/pull/94) which seems to say that the whitespace removal is no longer supported by prettier-plugin-tailwindcss. But I'm confused because that space somehow gets removed in my Vue projects. I don't know why it doesn't work with React, but I suspect it's because Prettier removes the extra spaces in Vue templates where the 'class' prop can be used, as opposed to the 'classname' prop in React.

Answer (score 3):

prettier-plugin-tailwindcss has been able to trim the classname to remove whitespace but now it no longer can. Check this [Github issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7560)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension like Run On Save.

Configure your settings.json some rule:
[Auto run command from vscode extension on file save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68059778/auto-run-command-from-vscode-extension-on-file-save)

And the pattern will be something like:

[regular expression to remove space inside quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606882/regular-expression-to-remove-space-inside-quotations)

settings.json:

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "match": "\\.tsx$",
           "cmd": "perl -i -pe 's/\\b\\s{2,}\\b/ /g' ${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```